# Keep financial data even when removing user from data base

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, architecture

I'm working on a system that manages clubs and associations.

One key factor of this system is that one person can be a member of more than one club.

Right now, I'm facing an issue where my system is loosing financial records references when one user is longer a member of an association. To visualize it a little better, I made a simplified version of the tables related to finances.

[image]

So basically I have one table that has the associations, one that has each group of associates, so the associate would be the identification for the family and then the members, that would be the dad, mom, son, etc. Each associate needs to have one and just one responsible, who would receive all the communication, manage the associate certificate, pay the bills.

All the associations work on a monthly subscription, paid by the member responsible, and it can also have others expenses, such as restaurants, rental of barbecue areas, party room, etc.

These finances are stored in the `tb_finance` table, which references the `tb_associate`. This is where my problem is today.

If one family decides they no longer wants to be part of the association, or (I think it's worse), they decide to sell their Certificate to another family, the finances will break.

I'm not loosing all info, but I'll lose the link between them. `tb_associate` and `tb_user` will never have their info deleted. But `tb_associate_member` will.

I thought about creating another table to create a direct reference with the user's and finances, for example, like this:

[image]

This way `tb_associate_finance` will never be deleted, thus keeping its user's reference.

I just don't feel like this is the best way to solve this problem. It seems to have a better and simple way to achieve this result.

For each member responsible, it's possible that they have an apiKey used by an external third party system integrated (similar to PayPal) to generate the bills for credit card, etc., to be paid.

Comment: I'm confused.  If the financing is tied to an association, what difference does it make when a user leaves that association?

Comment: @RickJames it’s tied to both association and associate, so I can filter by either one of them. The problem is that when I remove the association with associate member I can’t get info such as responsible name, email, etc… to display as historical financial data. Hopefully I can explain it better now :)

Comment: @RickJames this way I can display for the association in their dashboard all finances but also display on the member what are the finances related to that user alone.

Comment: So, you need an optional (NULLable) connection between a user and finance?